# Caught TypeError while rendering: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying really hard to work with the book "Practical Django Projects", but this stuff it's not working. You can find my code so far [here.](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/practical-django-projects/src/79e75633cbd4/coltrane/models.py) (Without the "Link" class. I've just added the get_absolute_url Entry class and all of a sudden I have a "Caught TypeError while rendering: unhashable type: 'dict'" error when trying to get to admin page. [Screenie of what I'm talking about.](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/5237/screenieol.jpg) I've never modified anything in that file showed in the error :(. What do i do with this?

EDIT: bug occurred after adding this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('coltrane_entry_detail', (), { 'year': self.pub_date.strftime("%Y"),
                                           'month': self.pub_date.strftime("%b").lower(),
                                           'day': self.pub_date.strftime("%d"),
                                           'slug': self.slug })
get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

That's from urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    (r'^$', 'archive_index', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_index'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_year'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_month'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 'archive_day', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_day'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/?(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_detail'),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but your code isn't loading at the moment.

As far as I can guess you're probably trying to use `dict` instance as a `dict` key.
For example, you can't do this:

```
a = {'1' : 'one'}
b = {a : 'two'}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you show me the line in your URLconf in which the `coltrane_entry_detail` url is named? At least [one old ticket on djangoproject.com](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10151) suggests that error may be caused by a misconfigured url pattern, and if you've just added a `get_absolute_url` method for your model I'm guessing you may have also just added the named view it refers to?

Comment: Added it in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your django environment setup with pip and virtualenv?  Your project has the following dependencies:

```
markdown==2.0.3
django-tagging==0.3.1
```

I've put the above in a file called `requirements.txt` at your project level.  Once you have installed pip, virtualenv and created a unique environment for that project, you can install the above as:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After the previous setup, you need to put `tagging` in `INSTALLED_APPS` of your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'cms.search',
    'coltrane',
    'tagging',
)
```

Delete your `cms.db` database file and run `python manage.py sycndb`.  You will need to provide a username and password for the superuser. The code is running fine on my end and I can access the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Some time this comes when we use HTTPResponse instance insted of render method

For ex:
In my case

`return HttpResponse(request, 'doctor_list.html', {'list': doctor_list})`

This remove with

`return render(request, 'doctor_list.html', {'list': doctor_list})`